# how to change python 3.8 default version to 3.7

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu.

my default version of python is:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

I installed python3.7:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Note, selecting 'python3.7-2to3' for regex
> 'python3.7' Note, selecting 'libpython3.7-stdlib' for regex
> 'python3.7' 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not
> upgraded.

after installed I don't know how to use python3.7 .

I'm trying below command but I got error:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

> update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/python3.7
> doesn't exist

I want to install this requirements:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
scipy==1.7.3
pillow==9.1.0
gdown
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu.

Comment: You can use conda. with this you can create multiple environments with different Python versions. this way you can use multiple Versions at the same time.

Comment: Instead of changing the default, consider to directly call the specific interpreter or even create a venv for the required version and dependencies. Relying on the default to have a specific version is brittle.